# Install specific version of laravel sail (8.1) for existing project

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to work with the repo of [Jeffrey Wey](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-From-Scratch-Blog-Project), which was done in Laravel 8 and does not work with Laravel 9.

I thought about doing it that way:

1. Install data from Jeffreys repo:

```
git clone git@github.com:JeffreyWay/Laravel-From-Scratch-Blog-Project.git blog
composer install
cp .env.example .env
```

2. Install Laravel 8 with ?
   `composer require laravel/sail`

=> Here I need help since I do not know how to tell composer to install an older version of laravel sail. If there is another method I should use, please let me know.

Comment: The repo you are cloning already installs laravel 8 when you run `composer install`  there's no need to require Laravel manually

Comment: But how to install laravel sail (which included several other container)?

Comment: `composer require laravel/sail` should work. The latest version of sail supports both Laravel 8 and 9

Answer (score 0):

Composer will install the modules which are included in the `composer.json` file which is available in that repo.

If you want to run it like for like, simply clone it and run `composer install` and it will install the specified, correct modules.